# Does "After The Rain With You" explain why Anna's fighting the 5th gym leader with a heavy disadvantage in Biri-Biri?

Tags: pokemon

[After The Rain With You's Bulbapedia Page](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/After_the_Rain_With_You), and the [story itself, in Japanese](https://novel-kimiame.pokemon.co.jp/#open)

[Anna's disastrous gym battle in Biri-Biri music video](https://youtu.be/shZyg5VFI1Y?t=94), losing all 3 of her Pokemon while only barely taking out the Gym Leader's first Pokemon, Lv 35.

It's not a totally unevolved team since Anna does have Dachsbun, which is at least Lv 26, but her other two are Pikachu and Fuecoco, the latter of which is therefore likely to be under the evolution level of 16, but we see that she also has a Gengar, which would be the type-effectiveness-based choice to use, so why doesn't she use it?

Or does the story give clear info that there's "ludonarrative dissonance", if you want to use that term, a.k.a gameplay and (side)story segregration instead of integration going on that somehow plays into an explanation?

Comment: Doing a quick machine translation of the story, it seems she did use Gengar - but in the story, her Crocalor, Pikachu, Dacshbun and Nacli all lost to Komala, Gengar took Komala out, but was then KO'ed by Dudunsparce's Drill Run.

Comment: @Showsni - Cool! I'd accept that as an answer if you mixed in the raw JPN and the translation so it's easy to double check!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the web novel version, it appears Anna instead loses whilst fighting with an advantage - she uses all five of her Pokémon on hand compared to Larry's three, but still is unable to beat him. The salient passage from the novel is:

> アオキが軽く会釈したのに合わせ、アンナもまた頭を下げた。 「お世話になります、アオキです。何とぞよろしくお願いします」
> 「あ、えーっと、アンナです。よろしくお願いします！」
> 　アオキはネクタイの結び目を軽く緩めると、さっそくモンスターボールを放った。現れたのは〈ゆめうつつポケモン〉のネッコアラだ。アンナもまた、同じタイミングでボールを投げる。アンナの一匹目はアチゲータだった。
> 　アオキのポケモンはノーマルタイプ。このタイプの特徴は、弱点がかくとうタイプしかないところだ。いままでネモは何度もアンナとポケモン勝負をしてきたが、彼女のポケモンがかくとうタイプの技を使っているところを見たことがない。
> 　状況はあまりよくないかもしれない……と、ネモはアンナのほうを見やった。彼女は身振り手振りでアチゲータに指示を伝えているところだった。
> 「アチゲータ、『やきつくす』！」 「ネッコアラ、『あくび』です」
> 　アチゲータの口から放たれた炎をかわし、ネッコアラは大きくあくびをした。それに釣られたように、アチゲータもあくびをする。そのまぶたは重たげに何度も下がり、口からはあくびが止まらない。睡魔にあらがえなかったのか、やがてアチゲータはその場で寝息を立て始めた。ねむり状態だ。
> 「『たたきつける』！」
> 　無防備になったアチゲータに、ネッコアラが攻撃した。それでもアチゲータは目を覚まさずダメージが重なっていき、やがてアチゲータは何もできないままにダウンした。
> 「アチゲータ！」 　アンナが鋭い声を上げる。明らかに動揺しているアンナとは対照的に、アオキはいたって冷静だった。
> 「これから挽回ばんかいするよ！　ゆけっ！　ピカチュウ！」
> 　アチゲータの次にアンナが繰り出したのは、〈ねずみポケモン〉のピカチュウだった。前回勝負し
> たときにはいなかったポケモンだ。ここからいったいどう巻き返すのだろうかと、ネモは期待を込めて試合の行方を見守った。
> 　だが、ネモの期待とは裏腹に、戦況はあまり変わらなかった。ネッコアラの攻撃に、ピカチュウは防戦一方だ。素早さの勝るピカチュウは回避を繰り返していたが、やがてしびれを切らしたアンナが攻勢に出た。
> 「ピカチュウ、『ほうでん』！」
> 　ピカチュウの頬にある電気袋から電撃が放たれる。——形勢逆転か。そう思われた刹那、不意にピカチュウが目を回してその場にダウンした。ピカチュウの『ほうでん』よりも先に、ネッコアラの『ふいうち』が相手にダメージを与えていたのだ。
> 　二人の戦いを、ネモは席に座ったまま冷静に分析する。アンナは必死に食らいついているが、作戦でどうこうできる以上にポケモンの力量の差が明白だ。
> 　ピカチュウがダウンしてからも、アンナは次々にポケモンを出した。三匹目はバウッツェル、四匹目はコジオ……そして最後に出した五匹目のポケモンがゲンガーだった。
> 「相手は弱ってるよ！　がんばって、ゲンガー！」
> 　アンナの声援に鼓舞されたのか、ゲンガーの渾身こんしんの『しっぺがえし』によってようやくネッコアラは倒れた。喜んだのもつかの間、アオキはすぐさま〈つちへびポケモン〉のノココッチを繰り出してくる。
> 　アンナの残りのポケモンはゲンガーのみ。それに対し、アオキはノココッチのほかにもう一匹温存している。
> 　ゴーストタイプの技はノーマルタイプのポケモンに、ノーマルタイプの技はゴーストタイプのポケモンに無効だ。ゲンガーもノココッチも、互いに相手に効果のある技は限られていた。
> 「ゲンガー、いくよ！」
> 　追い詰められたアンナがテラスタルオーブを使用する。ゲンガーはまばゆい光を放ち、テラスタルした。一方のアオキはテラスタルしてくる素振りさえ見せず、冷静にノココッチに指示を出す。
> 「ノココッチ、『ドリルライナー』！」
> 　アオキのノココッチの攻撃が、ゲンガーに真正面から決まった。激しい衝撃に耐えかね、ゲンガーはヨロヨロと体勢を崩した。重いダメージにあらがい、必死に立ち上がろうとしていたが、やがて糸が切れたかのようにその場に倒れ込んだ。わっと食堂内から歓声が上がる。
> 　アンナの手元にはもう戦えるポケモンがいない。アオキの勝利だ。——そして、アンナにとってはこれが初めての敗北だった。
> 「……勝負、ありがとうございます。お疲れ様でした」
> 　ノココッチをボールに戻し、アオキが淡々と頭を下げる。アンナは何も言わなかった。下を向いたまま、その場でじっと自身の足元を見つめている。
> 「アンナ？」
> 　様子がおかしくなったことに気づき、ネモは思わず席から立ち上がりかけた。だが、それよりも先にアンナはハッと我に返った様子で勢いよく頭を下げた。
> 「す、すみません。ぼーっとしてました。アオキさん、勝負してくれてありがとうございました！」
> 　礼を言うアンナに、観客たちから「よくやったね」「がんばってたよ」と温かい声援が飛んだ。アオキは無表情のまま首を横に振る。
> 「いえ、業務なのでお気遣いなく」
> 　バトルコートからアンナが降り立つ。アンナは最後までネモの存在に気づくことなく、ふらふらとした足取りで食堂から去っていった。木製の扉の向こうへと消えていく彼女の背中を、ネモは黙って見守ることしかできなかった。
> 「アンナ、大丈夫かな……」

Or, running that through Google Translate:

> Larry gave a slight nod, and Anna also lowered her head.
> "Thank you for your help, Larry. Thank you very much."
> “Ah, um, I’m Anna. Nice to meet you!”
> Larry loosened the knot on his tie and immediately released a Pokéball. What appeared was the Drowsing Pokémon, Komala. Anna also throws her ball at the same time. Anna's first Pokémon was Crocalor.
> Larry's Pokemon is a normal type. The characteristic of this type is that its only weakness is the Fighting type. Nemona has had many Pokémon battles with Anna, but she has never seen her Pokémon use fighting-type moves.
> The situation might not be so good... Nemona looked at Anna. She was conveying her instructions to the Crocalor through gestures.
> "Crocalor, 'Incinerate'!"
> "Komala, it's 'Yawn'."
> Dodging the flames released from Crocalor's mouth, Komala yawned loudly. As if seduced by this, Crocalor also yawns. Her eyelids drooped repeatedly, and she couldn't stop yawning. As if unable to resist the drowsiness, Crocalor eventually began to sleep on the spot. She's fast asleep.
> "'Slam'!"
> Komala attacked the now defenceless Crocalor. Even so, Crocalor did not wake up, and the damage continued to pile up. Eventually Crocalor went down without being able to do anything.
> “Crocalor!”
> Anna raises a sharp voice. In contrast to Anna, who was clearly upset, Larry remained calm.
> "I'm going to try to recover from now on! Let's go! Pikachu!"
> The next thing Anna brought out after Crocalor was the Mouse Pokémon, Pikachu. It's a Pokémon that wasn't there the last time they fought. Nemona watched the match with anticipation, wondering how she would recover from this point.
> However, contrary to Nemona's expectations, the battle situation did not change much. Pikachu is only able to defend itself against Komala's attacks. Pikachu, who was superior in speed, repeatedly dodged, but eventually Anna grew impatient and went on the offensive.
> "Pikachu, 'Discharge'!"
> An electric shock is fired from the electricity sacs on Pikachu's cheek. Is this the comeback? At that moment, Pikachu suddenly rolled its eyes up and fell down on the spot. Komala's 'Sucker Punch' dealt damage to the opponent before Pikachu's 'Discharge'.
> Nemona calmly analyses the fight between the two while sitting in her seat. Anna is desperately trying to bite back, but the difference in the Pokémon's abilities is overshadowing anything that can be done by strategy alone.
> Even after Pikachu went down, Anna sent out Pokémon one after another. The third Pokémon was Dachsbun, the fourth was Nacli... and the fifth Pokémon that was finally released was Gengar.
> "The opponent is weak! Do your best, Gengar!"
> Perhaps inspired by Anna's cheers, Komala finally fell due to Gengar's 'Payback', attacking with all his might. The joy was short-lived, as Larry immediately brought out Dudunsparce, the Land Snake Pokémon.
> Anna's only remaining Pokémon is Gengar. On the other hand, Larry still has one other in reserve, in addition to Dudunsparce.
> Ghost-type moves have no effect on Normal-type Pokémon, and Normal-type moves have no effect on Ghost-type Pokémon. Both Gengar and Dudunsparce had limited techniques that were effective against each other.
> "Gengar, let's go!"
> Anna, cornered, uses her Tera Orb. Gengar emitted a bright light and terrastalized. Larry, on the other hand, calmly gives instructions to Dudunsparce without showing any signs of terastallizing.
> “Dudunsparce, 'Drill Run'!”
> Larry's Dudunsparce's attack landed directly on Gengar. Unable to withstand the intense impact, Gengar staggered and lost his balance. He struggled against the heavy damage, desperately trying to stand up, but then fell to the ground as if a string had been cut. A cheer goes up from inside the cafeteria.
> Anna no longer has any Pokémon on hand that she can fight with. It's Larry's victory. And for Anna, this was her first defeat.
> "...Thank you for the match. Thank you for your hard work."
> Larry lowered his head indifferently as he returned Dudunsparce to the ball. Anna said nothing. She looks down, staring at her feet.
> "Anna?"
> Noticing that something was wrong, Nemona almost stood up from her seat. But before that, Anna seemed to come to her senses and bowed her head vigorously.
> "I-I'm sorry. I was dazed. Thank you, Larry, for competing!"
> As Anna thanked him, the audience cheered her on, saying, "You did a great job!" and "You did your best." Larry shakes his head without expression.
> "No, it's my job, so don't worry about it."
> Anna steps down from the battle court. Anna hadn't noticed Nemona even after the end, and she left the diner with unsteady steps. Nemona could only watch silently as she disappeared behind the wooden door.
> "Anna, are you okay..."

The description is fairly in depth, and you can see all of Larry's Pokémon only use moves they actually have in the game. It seems as though his Pokémon are simply too high level for most of Anna's; Crocalor unfortunately falls victim to most likely a maximal length sleep from yawn, Pikachu is easily taken out by Sucker Punch, and Komala also manages to finish off Dachsbun and Nacli. I'd guess Gengar has the Poison Tera type, explaining why Drill Run is still so effective, but the story seems a little unclear on that (in an earlier fight where Gengar terrastalizes it mentions poison resists grass, though it doesn't explicitly state the type that I can see).

From a story perspective, Anna had to lose here to help her grow as a person. This is her first loss, and as she heads out into town it begins to rain. Nemona worries about her and ends up running through the rainy town to look for her - leading to the titular "after the rain with you" scene.

> A film of tears covered the surface of Anna's eyes. Her eyes sparkled intensely every time she blinked, but nothing fell from them.
> "Crocalor, Pikachu, Dachsbun, Nacli, and Gengar all tried their best, but we lost. I felt like I wasn't good enough. I was thinking about all kinds of things by myself, like what I should have done... I was afraid Nemona would be disappointed if she found out that we lost, even though she had high hopes for us."

[image]

I'd imagine the music video cuts down Anna's five Pokémon to three for timing or balance purposes; you still get the basic idea (that she lost badly) without needing to see an extra two Pokémon KOed, and it fits more nicely on the screen to have three against three, rather than squishing Anna's five to fit into the space or having two blank areas on Larry's side.